# External and color contours in barplot - ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a barplot showing proportion of factors in two categories. I would like to know if there is a way to make the output with the black line contouring the extern and each color (factor) but not every observation.  I saw there are other questions related but not with stat "identity", position "fill". Here's an example code, forgive the mistakes. Live long and prosper.

```
view(starwars)

require(tidyverse)

mydf <- starwars |> 
  drop_na() |> 
  select(gender, species) |> 
  group_by(gender, species) |> 
  add_count()

mydf |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = gender, y = sum(n),
           fill = species))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", width = 0.4,
           color = "black")+
  theme_classic()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcqhb.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "to make the output with the black line contouring the extern and each color (factor) but not every observation"?

Comment: @Friede I add the picture for more clarity; I would like to not to have the black lines inside the bar and have the black line to contour the all column and each different color. For example in feminine "human" I would like to remove the two black bars inside the green

Answer (score 1):

You just need to summarize the data correctly ahead of the plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

starwars |> 
  drop_na() |> 
  count(gender, species) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = gender, y = n, fill = species)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = 0.4, color = "black") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>